# Recover from System Image without Optical Drive

Tags: windows-10

I have a system image saved on an external hard drive that I wish to apply to a new laptop. The problem is that the machine has no optical drive. Using the Recovery Options in Windows 10 to recover a system image will ask for a System Repair Disc. Unfortunately I don't have an external cd drive either.

I've tried to create a Recovery Drive on a second external hard drive and boot from that (http://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/) but going through that process still ultimately asks for a Repair Disc.

Any tips on how to get around this so I can recover from the image short of buying an external optical drive?

Comment: So put the recovery disk on a flash storage device.

Comment: @Ramhound The wizard doesn't give the option to select a USB device to create a repair disc, I receive a message that no cd writer can be found and the recovery wizard closes.

Comment: [It should](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/650x530ximage145.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.Z8vobTo32s.png)

Comment: @Ramhound I've created a Recovery Drive but when I boot from it I go through Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > System image recovery. I can then select the image I want but I'm still asked to insert or create a repair disc at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Finally recovered from the image. Had to create a USB Windows 10 installation drive, boot from it then during the setup process select Repair System and select the System Image. I tried every other process I could find before this worked.